# Lexer antlr3 token problem

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, token, lexer

Can I construct a token

```
ENDPLUS: '+' (options (greedy = false;):.) * '+'
       ;
```

being considered by the lexer only if it is preceded by a token `PRE`without including in ENDPLUS?

```
PRE: '<<'
       ;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, AFAIK, this is not possible "out of the box". One only has *look-ahead-control* over the tokens stream in the lexer or parser by using the attribute `input` and calling `LA(int)` (look-ahead) on it. For example, the following lexer rule:

```
Token
  :  {input.LA(2) == 'b'}? . 
  ;
```

matches any single character as long as that single character is followed by a `b`. Unfortunately, there's no `input.LA(-1)` feature to look behind in the token stream. The `{...}?` part is called a "syntactic predicate" in case you're wondering, or wanting to Google it.

A discussion, and some pointers on how to go about solving it, are given here: http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2004-July/008673.html

Note that it's `{greedy=false;}`, not `(greedy=false;)`.

Comment: Looking at the code for IntStream.java, negative integers are allowed as a parameter to LA and will get prior matched tokens.  So it just becomes a matter of checking prior matched tokens, hopefully nioo can limit how far back to check.  Maybe other languages are different, but Java will allow you to check prior tokens.

Comment: @WayneH, I'll check it out, thanks. Hopefully nioo will read you comment as well.